# How to round the number to a whole value?

Tags: python

I have 2 numbers and I want to divide them and the result I want is like this:

```
a = [12, 14]
b = [5, 3] 
for k in range(len(a)):
   print(math.ceil(int(a[k]) / int(b[k])))
```

I want the output look like this:

```
12 / 5 = 2.4 => 2
14 / 3 = 4.6 => 5
```

Comment: Use f-strings like `print(f"{a[k]} / {b[k]} = {a[k]/b[k]:.2} => {round(a[k]/b[k])}")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why use `math.ceil` when you can use `round()`.

```
print(round(int(a[k]) / int(b[k])))
```

with `round` you can control how many number you need:

```
>>>  print(round((a[k] / b[k]), 3))
2.4
4.667
```

You can use `f-string` and control how many numbers you need:

```
>>> print(f'{(a[k] / b[k]):.3f}')
2.400
4.667
```

Answer (score 1):

just replace `math.ceil` with `round`

as in :

```py
a = [12, 14]
b = [5, 3] 
for k in range(len(a)):
   print(a[k], "/", b[k], "=>", round(int(a[k]) / int(b[k])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `math.ceil` which is the ceiling of a number, so for example ⌈2.4⌉ = 3, ⌈2.8⌉ = 3 use just `round()`.

```
a = [12, 14]
b = [5, 3] 
for k in range(len(a)):
   print(round(int(a[k]) / int(b[k])))
```